# Loss of precision - warning with usage of srand

Tags: c++, c, srand

I am trying to use srand along with time for randomized value. If I look at 
srand function it takes unsigned int - but if we initialize it with time which seems to have long long value - so compiler keeps complaining about loss of precision warning. Any better way to do things ?

```
// srand definition
void srand (unsigned int seed);
// using srand with time to seed random value
srand(time(NULL));
```

warning 712: (Info -- Loss of precision (arg. no. 1) (long long to unsigned int))

Comment: Simple soulution: cast to `unsigned int`.

Comment: @Olaf: Yes, that will probably silence the warning -- but IMHO it's an annoying workaround, since the cast merely specifies the same conversion that would have happened anyway. It's also prone to error if you get the type wrong.

Comment: so seems from all answers suggestion is to just to typecast it or ignore the compiler warning-

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: I tried it on both VC++ and gcc/Linux - got same warning at both places

Comment: Casting is **no workaround**, but the C way to tell the compiler you know what you are doing and to shut up for this specific cast. That's why you shall **never** use casts just you think they look fancy or a **different langauge like C++ requires it - as for `malloc`, e.g.

Comment: Btw: C or C++! These are different languages. Choose one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C++, look into `<random>`. It has much better PRNGs.

If you're limited to `rand`, you can, in this case, ignore the warning, or better, tell the compiler you don't care by explicitly casting `(unsigned)time(NULL)`.

Comment: I guess that's the answer that I am getting from everyone - will go ahead and implement it that way.. thanks rici

Answer (score 0):

Putting it to simple logic, it makes a good sense that you lose precision when you use a `long long` instead of an `unsigned int` and that the compiler warns you for this.
(`long long` can represent a bigger range of numbers, you can check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz.aspx) the difference).

If you think that despite the loss your needs are covered, you can either cast it to an `unsigned int` or simply ignore the warning.